# How to fetch whatId label in salesforce formula field

Tags: community, formula, formula-field, salesforce-id

I have requirement where in WhatId should be able to display parent name(label) in formula field, i have tried using what.Name in formula field but it displays an error.

The below code fetches the 15 digit id of respective parent.
IF( NOT(ISNULL(WhatId )), WhatId,  '')

so far the solution given in the other links are possible by using trigger but i dont want to use triggers.

Comment: As WhatID could be a bunch of objects. I believe you cannot use it in a formula

Comment: @m Peixoto thanks for your reply can u suggest me any alternate work around except trigger.

Comment: Maybe, a Process builder....

Comment: @m peixoto i have checked using process builder too it shows only id.

Comment: you could create a Process Builder that call a Flow, In the flow, you can query the object that you want and update a field, for example...

Comment: @m Peixoto thank you i will try out your approach.